# Phonegap Fail to start GeoLocation Service

Tags: android, cordova, w3c-geolocation

I am working on Android app with PhoneGap 1.5.0.
Currently, I have a problem with the GeoLocation service being started. and here is the weird thing. I have 3 Android devices HTC Vivid, Galaxy S and Galaxy Tab (Android ver: 2.3.6, 2.3.4, 2.2).

When I called

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){....});
```

it gave me error of "Fail to Start GeoLocation Service". That is only happened on my HTC phone, the rest of my devices are working fine and able to get the current position.

Would someone able to help, please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is the "Use GPS satellites" option enabled in the device?

Comment: I even upgrade my phonegap to 1.7.0 and it still have the same problem. The same problem won't occur in my older devices (Galaxy S and Galaxy Tab 7.0). I suspect it is compatibility issue.